# Posso postar um "anúncio"?

Tags: debate, divulgação, autopromoção

Eu gostaria de saber se posso/devo postar um anúncio de uma linguagem de programação didática que desenvolvi. A ideia é tentar atrair pessoas para testar a linguagem.

Sei que provavelmente a quantidade de pessoas que vai de fato ir atrás para dar uma olhada será pouca, mas eu gostaria de um canal para apresentar para mais gente.

Eu vivo mais no mundo acadêmico, então eu estou sempre meio desligado dos modismos da vez.

Talvez haja algum lugar mais apropriado para isso e, caso alguém conheça, eu agradeço se puder me informar.

Comment: Os únicos lugares em que podemos postar conteúdo são nas perguntas e respostas do site, e estas possuem regras bem claras quanto a anúncios e divulgação de produtos em geral: veja na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), em especial a seção "Evite promoção pessoal flagrante" - entendo que se fizer um post somente para divulgar algo, cai neste caso, e ainda pode gerar sinalização de spam, o que por sua vez gera penalização da sua conta (feito automaticamente pelo sistema, caso seja confirmado o spam). Resumindo, a resposta é "não" :-)

Comment: O Reddit, dependendo da comunidade, parece ser um lugar apropriado e na moda para divulgar e solicitar testadores (nesse caso recomendo baixar o app em vez de tentar usar pela interface Web). Em outras comunidades relacionadas a computação da rede StackExchange acredito que não seja apropriado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obrigado por perguntar. Sinto muito, mas não, as regras do site não permitem utilizar postagens para divulgação ou anúncios de qualquer tipo.

Os lugares onde você pode divulgar links para seus projetos/trabalhos são:

- Seu texto de perfil
- As salas de [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com) do site